# ZF2 - Working with a one to one join and collections with ORM Doctrine

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am attempting to join two tables. My user table and my user_role_linker table.

user table: user_id, name, email... etc.
user_role_linker table: user_id, role_id (this is from ZfcUser / BjyAithorize)

I am listing my users to a view and I want to include their role in the view. Fortunately the user_role_linker table uses the actual role name as its ID so I only have to do a single join.

I have been told to achieve this I need to use a "collection". I have read all about collections in the [Doctrine Manual](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#collections) and I have put some code down. I am however a little unsure how to put it all together. This is what I have thus far:

```
<?php
    namespace Administration\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\ORM\MApping\OneToOne;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /** @ORM\Entity */

    class User {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="user_id")
         */
        protected $user_id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="parent_id") */
        protected $parent_id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="title") */
        protected $title;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name") */
        protected $name;


       //etc.

        //Setters and getters

        public function getUserId() {
            return $this->user_id;
        }


        public function setTitle($title) {
            $this->title = $title;
        }

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }


       //etc.

       //Constructor to setup the collection

        /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="user_id") **/
        private $user_role;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->user_role = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        public function getUserRole()
        {
            return $this->user_role;
        }

    }
```

My UserRole entity looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Administration\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\MApping\OneToOne;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class UserRole {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="user_id"))
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="role_id") */
    protected $role_id;

    public function getRoleId() {
        return $this->role_id;
    }


}
```

To grab the users I have a function that is called form the controller and I suspect I should be setting up the collection at this point...

```
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('Administration\Entity\User')->findAll();
    }
```

According to the docs I shouls be doing something like this:

```
$user_group = new UserRole();
$user = new User();
$user->getUserRole()->add($user_group);
```

I am not 100% sure at this point... can anyone point me to some tutorials or working examples for this?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZF2 - Doctrine ORM, Simple Table Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468267/zf2-doctrine-orm-simple-table-join)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is many to many association: one user can have many roles, one role can be assigned to many users. Doctrine will create join table for you.

Assuming that you have `Role` entity:

User entity:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="parent_id") */
    protected $parent_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="title") */
    protected $title;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name") */
    protected $name;

    // roles association:

    /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
    protected $roles;

    // getters & setters

    public function __construct() {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

You don't need `UserRole` table. Doctrine will create `users_roles` table that links `User` and `Role` entity.

Then you add role to user:

```
$user = new User();

// $role1 and $role2 are instances of Role entity
$user->getRoles()->add($role1);
$user->getRoles()->add($role2);
```