# ZF2 - Doctrine ORM, Simple Table Join

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am currently learning how to use Doctrine ORM with ZF2 and currently my goal is to retrieve data from a simple table join and display it to screen.

I have read the documents and it looks pretty simple to do.

These are my tables:

```
user
------------------------
|user_id | name | email   |
--------------------------
| 1      | John | j@b.com |
--------------------------
| 2      | Bob  | b@j.com |
--------------------------

user_role_linker
--------------------------
|user_id | role_id        |
--------------------------
| 1      | administrator  |
--------------------------
| 2      | staff          |
--------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is a list to my view as follows:

```
ID       Name       Email      Role              Actions
--------------------------------------------------------
1        John       j@b.com    Administrator     Edit
2        Bob        b@j.com    Staff             Edit
--------------------------------------------------------
Paging goes here
----------------
```

This is what I currently have and it seems to work except I am not sure how to grab the joined table data:

```
User entity::

<?php
    namespace Administration\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /** @ORM\Entity */

    class User {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
         */

        protected $user_id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="parent_id") */
        protected $parent_id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name") */
        protected $name;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="email") */
        protected $email;

        //Setters and getters

        public function getUserId() {
            return $this->user_id;
        }

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getEmail() {
            return $this->email;
        }

        public function setEmail($email) {
            $this->email = $email;
        }

        /**
        * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserRoleLinker")
        * @JoinTable(
        * name="user_role_linker",
        * joinColumns={
        *   @JoinColumn(
        *     name="user_id",
        *     referencedColumnName="id")
        *  },
        * inverseJoinColumns={
            *   @JoinColumn(
             *     name="user_id",
             *     referencedColumnName="id",
             *     unique=true)
             * })
        */
        private $role_id;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->role_id = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /** @return Collection */
        public function getRoleId()
        {
            return $this->role_id;
        }

    }
```

User role linker entity::

```
 <?php
    namespace Administration\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class UserRoleLinker {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="role_id") */
    protected $role_id;

    /** @param User|null */
    public function getRoleId() {
       return $this->role_id;
    }
}
```

My Administration controller::

```
public function usersAction() {
   $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
   $userFunctions = new UserFunction($em);
   $userArray = $userFunctions->getUsers();
   $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('users' => $userArray));
   return $viewModel;
}
```

This calls my UserFunctions class::

```
public function getUsers()
{
    //This function returns the users
    return $this->em->getRepository('Administration\Entity\User')->findAll();
}
```

And in my view I list the data like this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($this->users AS $user) {
?>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td width="5%"><?php  echo $user->getUserId(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->getName(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->getEmail(); ?></td>
    <td class="center">*** HOW DO I SHOW THE ROLE ?? ***</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

How do I grab the role to show in the view?

Comment: have a look at the association mapping here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the correct relationship between user and role in your entity definition.
I am not sure why you use a linker table here. Do you want to actually have a many to many relationship between user and roles (every user can have several roles?).
If not you can easily move the role id into the user table and then you define a `ManyToOne` relationship between user and role.

Your user table would then look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|user_id | name | email   | role_id       |
-------------------------------------------
| 1      | John | j@b.com | administrator |
-------------------------------------------
| 2      | Bob  | b@j.com | staff         |
-------------------------------------------
```

I would suggest to take a look at `ManyToOne` with user as the owning side. You can check how to properly define your unidirectional many to one relation inside your entity definition here in [the Doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)

After that you can simply call `$user->getRole();` in your view...

### EDIT

Answer to fix a one to many using a join table:

This is also described in the [doctrine documentation here...](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

You need three tables; a user table, a role table and a user-role-linker table
The user is an entity, the role is an entity the role-linker table is not an entity in your case. You should drop that entity, the linker table is only used for connecting the user and role in the database.

**User table**

```
---------------------------
|id      | name | email   |
---------------------------
| 1      | John | j@b.com |
---------------------------
| 2      | Bob  | b@j.com |
---------------------------
```

**Role table**

```
-----------------
| id            |
-----------------
| administrator |
-----------------
| staff         |
-----------------
| guest         |
-----------------
| another role  |
-----------------
```

**Linker table**

```
--------------------------
|user_id | role_id       |
--------------------------
| 1      | administrator |
--------------------------
| 2      | staff         |
--------------------------
```

In your user entity:

```
/** ONE-TO-MANY UNIDIRECTIONAL, WITH JOIN TABLE ONLY WORK WITH MANY-TO-MANY ANNOTATION AND A UNIQUE CONSTRAINT
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Administration\Entity\Role")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role_linker",
  *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
  *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
  *      )
  */
protected $roles;

/**
 * Get roles.
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

/**
 * Add a role to the user.
 *
 * @param Role $role
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addRole(Role $role)
{
    $this->roles[] = $role;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove a role from the user
 *
 * @param Role $role
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function removeRole(Role $role)
{
    $this->roles->removeElement($role);

    return $this;
}
```

Your role entity:

```
/**
 * An example entity that represents a role.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @property string $id
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get the id.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I think this should help you solve it...

Maybe you should add the following to your application module:

```
public function doctrineValidate(MvcEvent $event){
    $application = $event->getParam('application');
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $validator = new SchemaValidator($entityManager);
    $errors = $validator->validateMapping();
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        // Lots of errors!
        var_dump($errors);
    }
}
```

And then in bootstrap:

```
$eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'doctrineValidate'));
```

in module:
Doctrine will help you by checking your entity definitions. It might tell you in advance that something is wrong in your entity definitions...

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing, but as you defined in your entities, you could get the roles collection using **User** entity **getRoleId**'s function. Then, for each **UserRoleLinker** entity you have to use, again, the **getRoleId** function, which will return the 'Administrator' or 'Staff' string. Loop Example:

```
$roles = $user->getRoleId();

foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
    $roleId = $role->getRoleId();
}
```

I suggest you to do it another way. One entity should be **User**, with a property called **roles**. On the other side you could have the entity **Role**. The link between them should be a [**One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) (which is the **user_role_linker** table).

Comment: I have attempted to get this to work using your suggestions, please take a look at the answer I added... getting some unusual notices, also the object is not getting the required info.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by lluisaznar (although I need a many to 1 relationship since each user only has one role).

I am trying the following:

```
<?php
    namespace Administration\Entity;
    //use stuff

    /** @ORM\Entity */

    class User {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
         */

        //setters getters

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
        private $role;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->role = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /** @return Collection */
        public function getRoleId()
        {
            return $this->role;
        }

    }
```

And the Role entity:

```
<?php
namespace Administration\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Role {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="role_id") */
    protected $role;

    /** @param User|null */
    public function getRoleId() {
       return $this->role;
    }


}
```

When I run this I get the following notices:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in trunk/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2611
```

and

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_id in trunk/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 121
```

Also the role is not being displayed, when I dump the $user object under role I get this:

```
 private 'role' => 
    object(DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\Administration\Entity\Role)[609]
      public '__initializer__' => 
        object(Closure)[595]
      public '__cloner__' => 
        object(Closure)[596]
      public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
      protected 'user_id' => null
      protected 'role' => null
```

Comment: If you have a `ManyToOne` relationship you don't need a linker table. Drop the linker table and add a `role_id` column to your user table. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: Yes - that is something I would normally have done. Unfortunately the linker table is part of BjyAuthorize / ZFCUser and it is not possible to remove it without asking for trouble each time the third party module is updated. Normally I would have done a simple sql join and not thought twice about this... seems a simple join in ORM requires a PHD in rocket science! :)

Comment: No a simple join is just a simple join :) I will look at your code if I have some time later today and help you out. Where is the problem right now? Or still the same issues?

Comment: Thanks Wilt, would appreciate that. I am up to speed with accessing the database via a standard entity. Where I am struggling is how to join two tables (such as the above) and return the required information to a view. Ideally I would like to add paging to that however I figure I need to get my head around joins first before I even think about paging.

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: Hi wilt, I have not had a chance to try yet but should be able to give it a bash tomorrow.

Comment: Hello? Would be nice to know if you solved it? Otherwise post why it is still not working.

Comment: Hi Wilt - I have been working on simpler modules for now. Recently  I learnt about view helpers and since my goal is to show the user role to screen I can likely do this with a helper. I am not sure if this is the ideal way to do it but will give it a bash soon and report back.